# how to make Qr code scanner in vs 2008

Tags: qr-code

guys im on a thesis and I want to implement an windows application using my webcam as a QR code scanner. Is this possible in vb.net 2008? what DLLs do i need 
Please Help sir :<

Comment: Have you tried looking for various components, such as "webcam to image visual basic", image manipulation in VB.net? I assume you want to write the logic for the QR reader as well so you'd have to read up on how that works. Google is your friend :)

Comment: yah sir. have searched about this "xzing". It reads QR code using webcam but theres no exact or clear tutorials on implementing it on .net. :(